# How do I use a countifs with a cell that includes multiple data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to return a count using multiple criteria. With only 1 piece of data in a cell it isnt an issue but I need to be able to add multiple days of week in one cell and then count all references that occur.

Here is the formula so far

`COUNTIFS(Data!$E:$E,">="&C$8,Data!$F:$F,"<="&C$9,Data!G:G,"="&$C$7,Data!H:H,"="&$C$6,Data!I:I,"Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun")`

See example

[image]

Comment: As your screenshot doesn't have column names it's not possible to identify cells in your formula, please post sample data which corresponds to your formula.

Comment: If I understand your formula, your criteria related to column I will need to wrapped with braces '{ }'. I think you can also refer to a range, but not a single cell with multiple criteria. Finally, when dealing with an array/range  you would wrap your countifs with `SUM`.

Comment: Try to provide more detail information and sample here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

The first is the thing at the end. Excel sees it as continuing the tests to perform for the "IFS" part of "COUNTIFS":  It tests I:I for the string "Mon", then it tests the string "Tue" for the string "Wed", and so on. Obviously, those tests, like seeing if the string "Thu" has the value "Fri" in it just make no sense and fail outright, thereby causing the errors you are getting. Even if Excel WOULD make the test, actually comparing the strings, those tests would fail in every case, giving you zeros for results.

Additionally, even changing that condition will not solve things as Excel's internal arrays, except for the new SPILL arrays, always have length limits. And they just END when they reach those limits. So the arrays based on entire columns aren't really tested since they end early and that makes them just strings, and unusable ones at that. (Internal arrays have to terminate a right curly brace, the "}", or they are not arrays. Since they don't form all the way to the end, they do not have any way to have that character. So each condition returns the fact that ZERO of the tests succeed, and therefore `COUNTIFS()` results in 0. (Remember, that's only AFTER you fix what you intended to be the last condition but which is four conditions, none of which will work.)

Fixing the full column thing is easy:  just don't use full columns. It's kind of lazy anyway, but much, much more important than someone preaching that at you is the fact it just won't work here. Pick some range larger than your data so you have room for growth, and see how it goes. I experimented with 30 lines and that worked fine. Thousands of rows should be fine too. But not over a million rows...

Fixing the days part though, that's a whole other story. I will not get into that because it would require either a different way to enter that data or a fairly complicated bit of formula to extract the days entered and to compare them to a list.

Getting to the list though... you seem to want to allow them to be any of the seven days of the week. So... why include that condition/test at all? Unless that isn't really what you intended in which case a much clearer explanation of that might be helpful. It looks to me like you want the days in column I's data checked against the five days shown above "Aug" and "Havant Station (Main)". There are better ways to do that than the involved work I mentioned last paragraph, and it simply requires you to change your list of conditions to check against to a slightly different, but VASTLY easier to use form. Your call on that though. If you have to have the awkward way it is now, then you must. But then you have to do a lot of hard work. Your spreadsheet so always your call.

I prefer easy. But there's a middling sort of way in which you place the hard work in a Named Range, then refer to the Named Range in this formula. So if you choose the hard route, that would be the version of hard (since it would be less hard!) to choose.